# Pass Table data from one HTML page to another

Tags: javascript, html

I need to populate `Homepage.html` data from `DashBoard.html` webpage.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Can this achieved using Java script ?

**Dashboard.html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td> PUE </td>
    <td> 1.5 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Power </td>
    <td> 336kWh </td>
    </tr>
</table>
Homepage.html
<table>
    <tr>
    <div class="Container">
    <h6> PUE is </h6>   #Need to display the data from Dashboard.html 
    </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: More information is needed. Are both pages from the same server? This is usually done by a server side language.

Answer (score 0):

You should really clarify your question, nevertheless depending on browser support the HTML5 storage API's might do exactly what you need.

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

Using it is really simple too:

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

The data is cleared after the session if you use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), you can also use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if you don't want it cleared.